# Appropriate response to: Would it be suitable to meet tomorrow noon at your office?

Tags: sentence-construction, register

Can I respond to:

> "Would it be suitable to meet tomorrow noon at your office?"

with:

> "Sure would!"

Comment: please provide  some context .

Comment: I don't think you'd find many native speakers who would use _suitable_ in this context. _Can we meet tomorrow at noon in your office?_ seems a more natural wording, but that rephrasing pretty much wrecks your question.

Comment: Rather than just ask if some phrasing is OK, could you add what your concern is, or why you think it might be unacceptable? Otherwise we are just proofreading.

Answer (score 1):

The question is very formal and polite.  It is a complete sentence; it uses the subjunctive; and it asks if it "suits" you to have the meeting at the proposed time.

> "Would it be suitable to meet tomorrow noon at your office?"

Your reply is very casual.  It is a sentence fragment; it does not include a subject; its only verb is an auxiliary verb; it uses a very informal sense of "sure"; and it does not have an object.

> "Sure would!"

Yes, you can respond this way.  A native speaker would understand you.  This answer is much less polite than the question.

If I read this dialog in an American novel, I would think that the author is juxtaposing two characters for comedic effect.  The person asking the question is old-fashioned, and is either a school teacher, a servant, or rich.  The person answering the question is making a point of acting like a "hick", and is either a "school boy", or is much richer than the environment in which he (or she) grew up.